# About ring with local units

Tags: ring-theory

A ring $R$, not necessarily unital, is said to be a *ring with local units* if there is a set $E\subseteq R$ of commuting idempotents such that for any $r\in R$ there is $e\in E$ such that $er=r=re$. Let us call such $e$ to be a *local unit for $r$*. A local unit for $r$ may not be unique. Anyway, a common (I dare say folklore) result about hence an equivalent definition of the ring is the following:

> If $(R,E)$ is a ring with local units, then arbitrary finite number of elements of $R$ have a common local unit. To be formally precise, if $r_1, r_2,\dots, r_n$ are arbitrary elements, then there is $t\in E$ such that $tr_i=r_i=r_it$ for each $i=1,2,\dots, n$.

Most papers in the literature which mention the result do not provide an explicit proof or simply dismissing it as an easy proof by induction. I thought the latter is really the case too but I have so far been unable to prove it. Even among arbitrary two idempotents in $E$ themselves I couldn’t quite see how to produce a common local unit.

Did I miss anything? I appreciate a hint instead of a full answer.

Edit: As an example of such a ring we may consider the ring of continuous real valued functions on $\mathbb R$ with compact support. Then it is a ring with local units where the commuting idempotents can be taken to be the characteristic function $\chi_I$ for each closed interval $I$. In this example the nature of characteristic functions easily prove the result above but I am not sure how to proceed in the most general case.

Comment: I am surely missing something, but if you take the direct sum of two copies of the field with two elements, then it seems to me that every element can be taken as a local unit. So I do not get the *arbitrary finite number* part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local unity common to $r_1$ and $r_2$ is $e_1+e_2-e_1e_2$.

Comment: +1 goes hand-in-glove with the lattice structure on the boolean lattice of central idempotents.  I never noticed this relationship with the elements the idempotent is the identity for, but it works out to make sense.